# Copy a folder overwriting ONLY smaller files in destination

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I have tons of PDFs in multiple sub-folders in */home/user/original* that I have compressed using *ghostscript* *pdfwrite* in */home/user/compressed*.
*ghostscript* has done a great job at compressing about 90% of the files however the rest of them ended up bigger than originals.
I would like to *cp* */home/user/compressed* to */home/user/original* overwriting files that are **only** smaller than the ones in destination while the bigger ones are skipped.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `find` command should work for this:

```
cd /home/user/original
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'file="$1"; rsync --max-size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file") "/home/user/compressed/$file" "/home/user/original/$file"' _ {} \;
```

The key part of this solution is the `--max-size` provided by `rsync`. From the `rsync` manual:

> `--max-size=SIZE`
>
> This tells rsync to avoid transferring any file that is larger than the specified SIZE.

So the `find` command operates on the destination directory (/home/user/original) and returns a list of files. For each file, it spawns a `bash` shell that runs the `rsync` command. The `SIZE` parameter for `--max-size` option is set by running a `stat` command against the destination file.

In effect, the `rsync` processing logic becomes this:

1. If the source file is larger than than the destination file, the
   `--max-size` parameter will prevent the source file from being
   transferred.
2. If the source file is smaller than the destination
   file, the transfer will proceed as expected.

This logic will result in only the smaller files being transferred from the source directory to the destination directory.

I have tested this in a few different ways, and it works for me as expected. However, you may want to create a backup of the destination directory before you try it out on your system.

Comment: This worked great. And with find and rsync only. Sweet.

Answer (score 2):

Perl's [-s](http://p3rl.org/-x) operator to the rescue!

Create an executable Perl script `overwrite-smaller`:

```
#!/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Copy;

my $file = shift;
(my $compressed = $file) =~ s/original/compressed/;
copy($compressed, $file) if -s $compressed < -s $file;
```

And run it for each file in the original directory:

```
find /home/user/original -type f -exec overwrite-smaller {} \;
```

Or, once in Perl, write the subtree walking there as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Copy;
use File::Find;

find({no_chdir => 1,
      wanted   => sub {
          my $file = $File::Find::name;
          -f $file or return;
          (my $compressed = $file) =~ s/original/compressed/;
          copy($compressed, $file) if -s $compressed < -s $file;
    }}, 'original');
```

Comment: I'll give it a go soon and let you know. Many thanks.